# Converting date into datetime not working?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert the date into datetime with some specific time with `combine` method but it didn't worked . It throws AttributeError.

AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
print(now)
required_date = now.date() - relativedelta(months=3)  # 3 months older date
print(required_date)
required_datetime = datetime.combine(required_date, datetime.time(09,00,00))
print(required_datetime)
LogEntry.objects.filter(action_time__range=(required_datetime, now)).delete()
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.combine`?

Comment: It's `datetime.datetime.combine` - a method of the datetime class of the datetime module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like this

```
datetime.datetime.combine()
```

you want to use the `combine` method of the `datetime` object that is in the `datetime` module